# Get name of element which was just clicked (JSFiddle)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page which contains multiple divs with similar but unique names. I also have a Jquery file which is supposed to simply change the classes of the correct div to `show` or `hide`.

I have a .click function which waits for any element with an id that starts with `replyToComment_`

This function will execute if I clicked a class with name `replyToComment_1` or `replyToComment_spaghetti` (although it will only ever be numbers)

When the function executes it needs to get that number on the end of the element that was just clicked and store it into a variable, so if `replyToComment_1` was clicked the variable needs to contain `1`

Hopefully this makes sense. Here's a JSFiddle which will help. http://jsfiddle.net/frayt/s06m8vc3/4/

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split and take the second element.

```
var parentCommentId = this.id.split('_')[1];
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/s06m8vc3/6/)

Answer (score 0):

In your click handler `this` refers to the element clicked.  So:

```
var parentCommentId = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mark but that doesn't seem to work. Amit's code above hit the nail on the head.

Comment: @Frayt, mine's essentially the same, except I got the `id` the jquery way:  http://jsfiddle.net/s06m8vc3/10/, regardless glad you got your answer. Cheers!

Comment: Hm, turns out I had a typo in my Jquery script tag, yours works fine!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure yours is the most efficient way to solve this problem, but here goes one solution to your question:

```
    var id = $(this).attr('id')
    var parentCommentId = id.substr(id.indexOf('_')+1);
```